# Uber like seek bar android

Tags: android, layout, styles, seekbar

I want to create the same thing as **Uber** did with seek bar

[image]

Is there any library that can help me achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try implementing a custom `Seekbar` with your own "`progressDrawable`" and "`thumb`" drawable. Then manage the specific behaviors programatically.

That's what i'm using to achieve something similar:

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekbar_task"
    android:layout_width="330dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:max="100"
    android:maxHeight="4dip"
    android:minHeight="4dip"
    android:progress="10"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_task"
    android:splitTrack="false"
    android:thumb="@drawable/tumb_task" />
```

Implement SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener in your Activity/Fragment to handle the different states

```
@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    int mProgress = seekBar.getProgress();
    if (mProgress > 0 & mProgress < 21) {
        mSeekBar.setProgress(10);
        sendStateResponse("TODO");
        setBoldText(0);
    } else if (mProgress > 20 & mProgress < 41) {
        mSeekBar.setProgress(30);
        sendStateResponse("START");
        setBoldText(1);
    } else if (mProgress > 40 & mProgress < 61) {
        mSeekBar.setProgress(50);
        sendStateResponse("STOP");
        setBoldText(2);
    } else if (mProgress > 60 & mProgress < 81) {
        mSeekBar.setProgress(70);
        sendStateResponse("CONTINUE");
        setBoldText(3);
    } else {
        mSeekBar.setProgress(90);
        sendStateResponse("FINISHED");
        setBoldText(4);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your progressDrawable.xml look like?  How does it include those tickmarks?

Comment: Please provide your progressDrawable and thumb,if you can.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [**here**](https://android-arsenal.com/search?q=seek) there are a lot of different libraries. 
[This one](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/919) might be similar to what you are searching for.